# how to compare in R the first character of a date variable with a number

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a column called Start_date (type is date) and I want to check the first number of the entry and compare it to a number.

I have achieved the result I want already using the following code:

```
filter(tripRawData_cleaned, Start_date < "2022-01-01")
```

This allowed me to find all rows older than the date.

Now I want to do this using a second method. By taking the first number of the Start_date '2' and comparing it to all the values in the column Start_date and select all the columns that do not start with '2'.

```
millenium <- substr((tripRawData_cleaned$Start_date),1,1)
millenium <- as.numeric(millenium)
str(millenium)
if(millenium < 2){
  print(tripRawData_cleaned$Start_date)
}
```

but this isn't working. the error message is :
'Error in if (millenium < 2) { : the condition has length > 1'
Thanks

Comment: An if() statement can only check one element in a vector at one time, but using this code we attempted to check every element in the vector at once.

Comment: Please(provide some data ->`dput(head(tripRawData_Cleaned))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if()` is not vectorized. One solution is to use a `for()` loop:

```
tripRawData_cleaned<-data.frame(Start_date=as.Date("1999-12-30")+0:3,
                                Value=0:3)

tripRawData_cleaned
#  Start_date Value
#1 1999-12-30     0
#2 1999-12-31     1
#3 2000-01-01     2
#4 2000-01-02     3

for (i in 1:NROW(tripRawData_cleaned)){
  if(substr(tripRawData_cleaned[i,"Start_date"],1,1) < "2"){
    print(tripRawData_cleaned[i,"Start_date"])
  }  
}

#[1] "1999-12-30"
#[1] "1999-12-31"
```

A fast, simplified vectorized method is:

```
tripRawData_cleaned[substr(tripRawData_cleaned$Start_date,1,1) != "2",]
```

Comment: the second one worked.. the first method doesn't... can I use a != operator in here: if(substr(tripRawData_cleaned[i,"Start_date"],1,1) < "2"){         

thanks for the answers a lot yet to learn

Comment: Does the first method work with simple sample data? Yes, `!=` works here. One caveat, an edge case if you have data from [the year 200 AD through 299 AD :)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3rd_century)

Comment: this is the result I get when I run the supply function. works nicely. tripRawData_cleaned$Start_date[sapply(substr(tripRawData_cleaned$Start_date,1,1), function(x) x<2)]

  [1] "0001-11-20" "0001-11-20" "0001-11-20" "0001-11-20" "0001-11-20" "0001-11-20" "0001-11-20" "0001-11-20" "0001-11-20" "0001-11-20"
 [11] "0001-11-20" "0001-11-20" "0001-11-20" "0001-11-20" "0001-11-20"

Comment: I ran the 'for (i in 1:NROW(tripRawData_cleaned))' and it worked.. but im confused as to why it prints out all the results when I use != and only the results I'm interested in when I use '<'

Comment: I get identical results with both `x<2` and `x!=2`, very odd situation, Perhaps a reboot is in order.